# SP.UI.ModalDialog (Please wait message)

Tags: c#, javascript, sharepoint

I am using an SP.UI.ModalDialog in my code in order to open a modal dialogbox in a sharepoint 2010 application.

Wanted to know how to display the message "please wait while the content loads" while the content is loading instead of showing a blank screen in the modal window (just like sharepoint does).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Remove width and height parameters. I had same problem and removing those solved it.

Here's the function that I use to open modal dialogs:

```
function OpenModalDialog(urlToOpen)
{
    var options = {
        url: urlToOpen ,
        allowMaximize: false,
        showClose: true,
        dialogReturnValueCallback: CloseCallback
    };

    SP.UI.ModalDialog.showModalDialog(options);
}
```